# How to put p5js animation as the background of a website?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have tried to think of a way to put what I have done in p5js as the thing that will be at the top of my website, with no results. There's gotta be a way, I will be more than happy if anyone has any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

P5.js works by drawing to a `<canvas>` element. I'd start by searching for something like "html use canvas as background" for a ton of results.

From there, you might also use the [P5.dom](https://p5js.org/reference/#/libraries/p5.dom) library to manipulate the HTML your sketch resides in, although this is probably not strictly necessary.

The best advice I can give you is to [break your problem down into smaller steps](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those steps on one at a time. Try to get this working with a simple sketch that just shows something like a single hard-coded circle. Then if you get stuck on a specific step, you can post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a specific technical question. Good luck.